# Reference on noncommutative PDE

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, oa.operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, semigroups-of-operators, geometric-analysis

I would like to ask if there is reference on semi-linear parabolic PDE (or more generally any kinds of PDE) with non-commutative unknown variable. For example, assume $u$ is a matrix-valued function (regularity assumption / integrability assumption to be specified), consider PDE (as an example): $\partial_t u - \Delta u + F(u) = 0$, where $F(u)$ is a nonlinear function of $u$ (if linear then this would not be much different from commutative case). For example, drawing analogy with PDE coming from harmonic map, we can take $F(u) = \langle\nabla u, \nabla u\rangle  = \sum_i \nabla_i u\nabla_i u$ where the product is matrix product. What can we say about PDE of this kind?

In the matrix case, this would be a system of semi-linear parabolic PDE. What are some general things we know about such systems of semi-linear PDEs? For example, is there a general maximum principle for such matrix valued case?

Furthermore, what do we know if we restrict u from general matrices to classical matrix Lie groups (such as $\mathrm{O}(n)$, $\mathrm{U}(n)$, $\mathrm{Sp}(n)$)?

On the other direction, what do we know if we consider more general non-commutative variable than $u$? Say $u$ is taken from a tracial von Neumann algebra. What can we say in that case?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I don't know about a reference for general theory, but here is a paper that studies one such equation (continuum (nonlinear advection)-type model for rotation matrices in 3D): Degond, Pierre, Amic Frouvelle, and Sara Merino-Aceituno. "A new flocking model through body attitude coordination." Mathematical Models and Methods in Applied Sciences 27.06 (2017): 1005-1049.

Comment: And here's another one (It studies coupled system, one variable is a vector and another is a symmetric tensor):Chen, Gui-Qiang, et al. "Global existence and regularity of solutions for active liquid crystals." Journal of Differential Equations 263.1 (2017): 202-239.

Comment: There are a lot of work done on **PDEs with vector-valued unknowns** (or systems). Generally vectored valued functions don't even admit a multiplication (they do not form an algebra) and therefore is more general than the "noncommutative" case, so if something holds for the vector valued cases it should also hold for your case. Maximum principles for weakly coupled parabolic systems are known, see e.g. Dow (1975) "STRONG MAXIMUM PRINCIPLES FOR WEAKLY COUPLED SYSTEMS OF QUASILINEAR PARABOLIC INEQUALITIES" (caps due to copy-pasting from article).

Comment: One special case of an equation similar to your example is Ricci flow. This has been studied in depth and Hamilton established a tensor maximum principle that plays a central role in the analysis. I wonder if some of that theory might be useful for your purposes.

Comment: My coauthor Dmitry Vorotnikov and Yann Brenier have been working on optimal transport of matrices, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.05064